# Spark DataFrame to MySql Time Stamp error

Tags: apache-spark

I Have Data Frame where schema is

```
id : long (nullable = false)
DDate: timestamp (nullable = true)
EDate: timestamp (nullable = true)
B1Date: timestamp (nullable = true)
B2Date: timestamp (nullable = true)
B3Date: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

when I'm using df.write.jdbc(url, "DF", prop) I am getting error

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Invalid default  value for 'DDate'
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at      sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorI    mpl.java:62)
at      sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorA    ccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
```

for every timestamp I am getting same problem how to solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

change `timestamp type` to `java.sql.Timestamp`

ex: `case class DfWithTs (ts: sent_at: java.sql.Timestamp, value: Int)`

`val ds = df.as[DfWithTs]`

and then write it, this will work with `jdbc`

Comment: even though I am using the case class java.sql.Timestamp I am getting same error .